# How to find out when a WebRequest is fully complete?

Tags: asp.net, http, powershell, httpwebrequest

There is a SharePoint site called http://mySPSite.com. It normally gets fully downloaded at the client side with images, CSS and JavaScript files in 12 seconds. I want to monitor the complete request using PowerShell such that it simulates the download of all the pages, in exactly the same way as a browser would.

What would be an appropriate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you can use this :

http://www.howtogeek.com/124736/stupid-geek-tricks-extract-links-off-any-webpage-using-powershell/

for accessing all link and image in your web site and making an array with them. Then download them in looop with this script :

```
$url = "http://website.com/downloads/Iwantthisfile.txt" 
$path = "C:\temp\thisisthefile.txt"
```

# param([string]$url, [string]$path)

```
if(!(Split-Path -parent $path) -or !(Test-Path -pathType Container (Split-Path -parent      $path))) { 
  $path = Join-Path $pwd (Split-Path -leaf $path) 
} 

"Downloading [$url]`nSaving at [$path]" 
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$client.DownloadFile($url, $path) 
#$client.DownloadData($url, $path) 

$path
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It would work only with clients that have PowerShell 3.0 installed.